# backdrop only shows on the top half of the screen when the table is refreshed

Tags: html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have backdrop that appears once the user click on the edit button or when the loading page at the start  and disappears once the modal is displayed or page is loaded. The backdrop works fine and highlights the whole page. But when I update my table with data and the table expands in height backdrop only shows at the top half of the screen. Please note that I am using Ajax to update my table without the need to refresh the page.
When loading the page backdrop works fine and covers the whole page:
[image]

After Updating the table using ajax and clicking one edit record to display the backdrop again I get the following:
[image]

How can I make the backdrop to cover the whole page when table is updated Code as follows:

```
   <div class="backdrop">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .backdrop {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

The backdrop is displayed as none and its set to be visible when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position fixed instead of absolute.
Also set height: 100vh and width: 100vw so it covers the whole screen.